# how to show locations in ios 6 apple maps with sharedApplication

Tags: ios, maps, ios6

in my app in ios 5 i have a button name show in map

forexample in a store detail view there is a showinmap button and this button goes to maps.google to show the user's current direction and the store direction and also it draws a line between these direction about how to go there

this was my method:

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%@,%@",lonlocation,latlocation];  

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

but in ios 6 as you know there is no google maps app. instead of that there is apple's new map app.

now my problem is how can i change my code to do the same job with apple map app in ios6 versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply replace `maps.google.com` by `maps.apple.com` in your URL and it works like a charm :)

```
CGFloat sysVers = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue;
NSString* hostName = (sysVers < 6.0) ? @"maps.google.com" : @"maps.apple.com";

NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%@,%@",hostName,lonlocation,latlocation];  

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

---

*[EDIT] As @Vagari pointed out in his answer, it seems that Apple integrated it better than I though and you can point all your URLs to `maps.apple.com` even in iOS5: Apple will automatically redirect your URLs to maps.google.com if you emit them from a device on iOS5!*

Comment: wow i never thought that it could be so easy :) thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

While AliSoftware saves a hop with his method. Technically you *only* have to change the `maps.google.com` to `maps.apple.com`. Apple pushes a redirect to devices not on iOS 6. Just wanted to clarify.